# What's wrong in my custom distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, parameters

i want to write this function

[image]

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{(x/\[Lambda])^\[Alpha]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {\[Lambda] > 0 && \[Lambda] > x, \[Alpha] > 0}]
data = {2.8, 1.8, 3.2, 5.0, 2.4, 4.8, 2.9, 2.9, 2.3, 3.2, 2.3, 2.0, 1.9, 3.3, 4.4, 6.7, 4.3, 1.9, 2.2, 3.3, 2.1, 4.0, 2.0, 3.1, 3.8,  3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 2.8, 2.1, 3.1}

mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist, ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindMaximum", MaxIterations -> 10000}]
```

but no result show
it' show like pic below
[image]

please anyone can help me

Comment: If $0\leq x \leq \infty$, how can the *constant parameter* $\lambda$ be greater than $x$? Also, the first expression in your `ProbabilityDistribution` doesn't look like a PDF.

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.com/power-function-distribution/          this distribution I want to write as a custom distribution please I want to write it no using power distribution function in mathmatica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation why *Mathematica* and other software packages have trouble with this particular probability distribution.

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(x/λ)^α, {x, 0, λ}, Assumptions -> {λ > x, α > 0}, 
   Method -> "Normalize"];

data = {2.8, 1.8, 3.2, 5.0, 2.4, 4.8, 2.9, 2.9, 2.3, 3.2, 2.3, 2.0, 
   1.9, 3.3, 4.4, 6.7, 4.3, 1.9, 2.2, 3.3, 2.1, 4.0, 2.0, 3.1, 3.8, 
   3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 2.8, 2.1, 3.1};

(* Determine log of the likelihood and do a bunch of simplifications *)
logL = Simplify[LogLikelihood[dist, data], Assumptions-> λ > Max[data]] //.
  Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b] /. Log[a_^b_] -> b Log[a] /.
  Log[Power[a_,-1]] -> -Log[a] // Expand

(* 33.497 α + 31 Log[1 + α] - 31 Log[λ] - 31 α Log[λ] *)
```

We see that because $\alpha>0$, $\lambda$ needs to be made as small as possible to maximize the log of the likelihood.  The smallest value possible is the maximum of the data values.

But when maximum likelihood estimators are on the border of possible values for a parameter, that can cause difficulties.

So the maximum likelihood value for $\alpha$ can be found with the following:

```
FindMaximum[{logL /. λ -> Max[data], α > 0}, α]
(* {-58.4039, {α -> 0.217198}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(x/λ)^α, {x, 0, λ}, 
   Assumptions -> {λ > 0, α > 0},
   Method -> "Normalize"];

dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* {λ > 0, α > 0} *)

PDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[dpa, CDF[dist, x] // Simplify]
```

[image]

```
data = {2.8, 1.8, 3.2, 5.0, 2.4, 4.8, 2.9, 2.9, 2.3, 3.2, 2.3, 2.0, 1.9, 3.3, 
   4.4, 6.7, 4.3, 1.9, 2.2, 3.3, 2.1, 4.0, 2.0, 3.1, 3.8, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 2.8, 
   2.1, 3.1};

mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist, 
  ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", 
    Method -> "FindMaximum", 
    MaxIterations -> 10000}]

(* {α -> 1.09548, λ -> 1.09548} *)
```

Or more simply,

```
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]

(* {α -> 1.09548, λ -> 1.09548} *)
```

**EDIT:** The parameter estimates are wrong. As indicated in the comments, different data sets result in identical estimates for the parameters. A bug report was submitted to Wolfram Tech Support (CASE:4954659)

Comment: i changed data but same parameters output   data = {0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 11.0, 
   12.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 21.0, 32.0, 36.0, 40.0, 45.0, 
   45.0, 47.0, 50.0, 55.0, 60.0, 63.0, 63.0, 67.0, 67.0, 67.0, 67.0, 
   72.0, 75.0, 79.0, 82.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 85.0, 85.0, 
   85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0};       or data={275, 13, 147, 23, 181, 30, 65, 10, 300, 173, 106, 300, 300, 212, 300, \
300, 300, 2, 261, 293, 88, 247, 28, 143, 300, 23, 300, 80, 245, 266}

Comment: i want to write alpha power distribution as custom distribution not use the defined alpha power distribution in mathematica

Comment: Yes, the estimated parameters using the custom distribution ( `ProbabilityDistribution`) are wrong. `FindDistributionParameters` is returning identical estimates for the different data sets. I will submit a bug report to Wolfram Tech Support.

Comment: This is a case where the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$ is the maximum of the data values.  Having the maximum likelihood estimator being on the border of possible values causes trouble for many software packages including *Mathematica*.